# how to bind object beneath another object in XCode Swift 3 so object below transition with the above one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, transition, xcode8

I want suggestions to achieve this. See below in attachment

What i did in "Details section" is i placed a tableview with one row in it to make it look like collapsable/expandable view.

Next section ("Buy Shares") is placed beneath it in view controller.
But when tableview row is collasped. The next view beneath it ("Buy Shares") is not going up with "Details view" section .

I want to move Buy shares view upwards too when details view is collasped.

No transition is applied to Buy shares view.
I am new in Swift IOS development. Any direction or any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Show the code that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: Thanks MwcsMac.
Actually its not an issue. Need suggestions how to achieve the "Buy shares section" to move up and down with tableview cell.

Comment: What show the code on how you are collapsing the table view.  Also what have you attempted that hasn't worked?